# why it throws an error when I pass a member function to sort()

Tags: c++, sorting, member-functions

I want to sort a vector whose member is pair<int, int>. So I write a function to compare two pairs.
It works when the function is in the outer space. But it throws an error when I try to write it as a member function. So why the error is thrown?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <set>
#include <map>
#include <algorithm>
#include <stack>
#include <queue> 


using std::pair;
using std::vector;
using std::sort;
using std::endl;
using std::cout;


// bool cmp(const pair<int, int>& p1, const pair<int, int>& p2)
// {
//     return p1.second < p2.second;
// }


class test
{
    public:
    bool cmp(const pair<int, int>& p1, const pair<int, int>& p2)
    {
        return p1.second < p2.second;
    }

    void my_sort(vector <pair<int, int>> &data)
    {
        sort(data.begin(), data.end(), cmp);
    }
};


int main()
{
    vector <pair<int, int>> data;
    for(int i=10; i>=0; i--)
    {
        data.push_back(pair<int, int>(10-i, i));
    }
    test a;
    a.my_sort(data);
    // sort(data.begin(), data.end(), cmp);
    for (auto &&i : data)
    {
        cout << i.first << '\t' << i.second << endl;
    }
    
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: hint: what is `this` in `test::cmp`?

Comment: You can make `cmp` static.

Comment: The compiler here tells you what the problem is  very clearly: [https://ideone.com/DzUkYS](https://ideone.com/DzUkYS)

Comment: The compiler is erroring because the **member function** `cmp` has the wrong signature.  The `sort` expects a **free standing function** or **class static function** or **lambda**, not a **member function**.

Comment: Use a projection in `std::ranges::sort(data, std::less(), [](auto &&t) { t.second; }`

Answer (score 4):

> So why the error is thrown?

Because `cmp` is a **non-static memeber** function and requires an object to be called on and so cannot be used as the comparison function object in `std::sort`.

To **solve** this you can either make `cmp` a `static` member function or use a `lambda` or implement `cmp` outside the class(at global namespace) as shown below:

##### Method 1

Make `cmp` a `static` member function.

```
class test{
    //other members 
    public:
        //make cmp static 
        static bool cmp(const pair<int, int>& p1, const pair<int, int>& p2)
        {
            return p1.second < p2.second;
        }

        void my_sort(vector <pair<int, int>> &data)
        {
//-----------------------------------------vvvvvvvvv--->cmp doesn't require an object to be called 
            sort(data.begin(), data.end(), test::cmp);
       }
};
```

[Demo 1](https://onlinegdb.com/fqa-yr5gv)

##### Method 2

Make `cmp` a free function.

```
//free function cmp outside class test
bool cmp(const pair<int, int>& p1, const pair<int, int>& p2)
{
        return p1.second < p2.second;
}
class test 
{
   //code here as before

   void my_sort(vector <pair<int, int>> &data)
    {
//-------------------------------------vvv---->no change here
        sort(data.begin(), data.end(), cmp);
    }
};
```

[Demo 2](https://onlinegdb.com/dE1-Mu5Hh)

##### Method 3

You can also use `lambda` as shown below:

```
class test
{
    public:
    

    void my_sort(vector <pair<int, int>> &data)
    {
//-------------------------------------vvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvv-->use lambda
        sort(data.begin(), data.end(), [](const pair<int, int>& p1, const pair<int, int>& p2)->bool
        {
            return p1.second < p2.second;
            
        }
        );
    }
};
```

[Demo 3](https://onlinegdb.com/xBTHvZbfS4)

Comment: [method4](https://onlinegdb.com/q9hjA9uqc) Although it's a bad practice in this particular case.

Comment: @pptaszni Yes, using `std::bind` is also an option.

Answer (score 1):

In order to use a member function with std::sort the function must be declared as static member function

Comment: It doesn't need to be static member function. It can be free function, lambda, `std::bind` of member function, a functor.

Answer (score 1):

To call a non-static member function you need to provide an object for which the function will be called.

Just define within the class `test` an operator-function and call the function `std::sort` within the member function `my_sort` the following way

```
std::sort( std::begin( data ), std::end( data ), *this );
```

Here is a demonstrative program.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <utility>
#include <vector>
#include <iterator>
#include <algorithm>

class test
{
public:
    bool operator ()( const std::pair<int, int>& p1, const std::pair<int, int>& p2 ) const 
    {
        return p1.second < p2.second;
    }

    void my_sort( std::vector<std::pair<int, int>> &data ) const
    {
        std::sort( std::begin( data ), std::end( data ), *this );
    }
};

int main()
{
    std::vector <std::pair<int, int>> data;
    for(int i=10; i>=0; i--)
    {
        data.push_back( std::pair<int, int>( 10-i, i) );
    }
    test a;
    a.my_sort(data);

    for (auto &&i : data)
    {
        std::cout << i.first << '\t' << i.second << std::endl;
    }
}
```

You can also call the function the following ways

```
test().my_sort( data );
```

or

```
std::sort( std::begin( data ), std::end( data ), test() );
```

Otherwise declare the member functions as static member functions. For example

```
#include <iostream>
#include <utility>
#include <vector>
#include <iterator>
#include <algorithm>

class test
{
public:
    static bool cmp( const std::pair<int, int>& p1, const std::pair<int, int>& p2 )
    {
        return p1.second < p2.second;
    }

    static void my_sort(std::vector <std::pair<int, int>> &data ) 
    {
        std::sort( std::begin( data ), std::end( data ), cmp );
    }
};

int main()
{
    std::vector <std::pair<int, int>> data;
    for(int i=10; i>=0; i--)
    {
        data.push_back( std::pair<int, int>( 10-i, i) );
    }

    test::my_sort(data);
//    std::sort( std::begin( data ), std::end( data ), test::cmp);

    for (auto &&i : data)
    {
        std::cout << i.first << '\t' << i.second << std::endl;
    }
}
```